# Share to NativeScript App with iOS Share Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am developing a NativeScript-Vue app. Among other features, the user should be able to share images from other apps (mainly WhatsApp) to my app, display them and perform some actions before sending them to the server.

While I was able to implement this readily on Android through intent filters and lifecycle events, it seems quite complicated on iOS.

Accessing the gallery and picking photos through NativeScript (imagepicker plugin) has already been implemented.

I have followed these guides:

- https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-receiving-shared-content
- https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/test/share-extension
- https://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/share-extension-in-ios-application-overview-with-example/

Continuing from the last link, I understood I have to "send" my images to the NativeScript app inside the `didSelectPost` method, but really I have no idea how to do this and I find no examples or guides online. I don't even know if it's possible.

Anyways, I'd like to access the images (PHAsset, bitmap, everything is fine) inside a specific NS-Vue page component, as I'm already doing on Android.

Has anyone solved this or should I contact Nick Iliev the man himself?

Comment: The `didSelectPost` method will be in your extension, not within your app. Did you manage to create your extension successfully yet?

Comment: I did, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Would you like to share your extension? I am looking for a simulair solution.

Comment: Maybe this link can shed some light to this question: https://dev.to/bryanleetc/creating-a-share-extension-in-nativescript-499k

Comment: Did your didSelectPost method work finally ? My app is not working for iOS 13.1 but working for previous iOS version.